# Add custom style to body tag in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, genesis

I've installed BlockAdblock to my site. It has also provided me an optional Javascript Blocking Protection.

For that, it requires me to add a style to my WordPress site's  tag.

Here is the style:

```css
style="visibility: hidden !important;"
```

I know how to add a custom class to the body tag but how do I add custom style to it?

I'm using Genesis Framework if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to dynamically add inline style, you can do this using wp_add_inline_style.

https://genesis.community/wiki/wp_add_inline_style-example/